# Haskell stack connection timeout

Tags: haskell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, haskell-stack

I have installed stack on WSL Ubuntu using WSL2 on Windows 10.  The installation completed successfully, but when I test stack with

```
stack path --local-bin
```

I get the following error message:

```
Writing implicit global project config file to: 
/home/jdgallag/.stack  /global-project/stack.yaml 
Note: You can change snapshot via the resolver field there.      
HttpExceptionRequest Request {                                                                                            
host                 = "s3.amazonaws.com"                                                                               
port                 = 443                                                                                              
secure               = True                                                                                             
requestHeaders       = [("Accept","application/json"),("User-Agent","The Haskell Stack")]
path                 = "/haddock.stackage.org/snapshots.json"                                                           
queryString          = ""                                                                                               
method               = "GET"                                                                                            
proxy                = Nothing                                                                                          
rawBody              = False                                                                                            
redirectCount        = 10                                                                                               
responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault       
requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                        
ConnectionTimeout
```

I have seen some other posts about issues like this one, but none that are resolved, and they are older.  Also, I am not on a proxy, this is my personal computer, and I turned the firewall completely off.  That said, when I attempt this over a vpn connection I get a different error.  Could it be an ssl/https issue since WSL2 is technically a different IP address from Windows, and so the connection is being blocked on the amazon side?

For the record when attempting the command on a VPN, the error I get is

```
Writing implicit global project config file to: 
/home/jdgallag/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml                         
Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field there.                                                         
HttpExceptionRequest Request {                                                                                            
host                 = "s3.amazonaws.com"                                                                               
port                 = 443                                                                                              
secure               = True                  
requestHeaders       = [("Accept","application/json"),("User-Agent","The Haskell Stack")]                               
path                 = "/haddock.stackage.org/snapshots.json"                                                           
queryString          = ""                                                                                               
method               = "GET"                                                                                            
proxy                = Nothing                                                                                          
rawBody              = False                                                                                            
redirectCount        = 10                                                                                               
responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault                                                                           
requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                        
(InternalException (HandshakeFailed Error_EOF))
```

#### Update

Reverting to WSL-1 "solves" the problem, so the issue is something specific to WSL-2.  I replicated the problem with a fresh install of Windows on a separate machine, but haven't found a way around the issue yet.

Comment: This happens to me also (WSL2 instance). I'd like to mention that I can successfully wget the resources that stack is attempting and fails to access.

Comment: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5063

Answer (score 4):

I have wls2 ubuntu 20.02 installed on my pc 
fixed this problem with changing the contents of /etc/resolv.conf

```
cd /etc
sudo *your favorite editor* resolv.conf
```

added Google DNS servers as

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

this fixed stack not working for me.

Comment: More details [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420)

Comment: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5063#issuecomment-1161588591 this works for me without having to change the dns.

Answer (score 0):

I use a macbook, ventura 13.4.1 -- 15-inch, 2018

I have tried:

###### not working for me: add google DNS nameserver to /etc/resolv.conf

```
# sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

###### not working for me: add entries to /etc/hosts

```
185.199.110.133 raw.githubusercontent.com
151.101.245.175 downloads.haskell.org
```

###### worked for me(probably because of all three steps) add proxy to terminal

```
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890
```